# Ionic 2 Select doesn't show the option text

Tags: android, select, ionic2

I'm using the Ionic 2 Select component exactly as the example shows (I actually copy/pasted the "Gaming" select) and when the popup appears showing the options, the option text is always missing.  It will show the radio buttons for each item, but just white-space for the text.  I've inspected the HTML to make sure it wasn't hidden by CSS, and the option text isn't in the HTML.

[image]

I've tried this in both the browser and running on an actual Android phone and get the same results.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my HTML:

```html
<ion-label>Gaming</ion-label>
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="gaming">
  <ion-option value="nes">NES</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="n64">Nintendo64</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="ps">PlayStation</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="genesis">Sega Genesis</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="saturn">Sega Saturn</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="snes">SNES</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

I don't have any custom CSS styles on this page at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the select component inside a list

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Toppings</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="toppings" multiple="true">
        <ion-option>Bacon</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Black Olives</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Extra Cheese</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Mushrooms</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Pepperoni</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Sausage</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

If you are trying to use a button and have a pop up select, use this:

```
   presentChooseGame() {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Choose Game',
        inputs: [
          {
            name: 'gameboy',
            value: 'gameboy',
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'GameBoy'
          },
          {
            name: 'gameboy2',
            value: 'gameboy2',
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'GameBoy2'
          },
          {
            name: 'gameboy3',
            value: 'gameboy3',
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'GameBoy3'
          },
        ],
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            role: 'cancel',
          },
          {
            text: 'Ok',
            handler: data => {
              console.log(data);
            }
          }
        ]
      });
      alert.present();
    }
```

hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was with live reload.  Once I did a full rebuild, the select values appeared.